# Should Inherit package-private field or create private one in all subclasses?

Tags: java, inheritance, private

I have trouble to understand the inheritance of some class fields.
In case of a field that is in all subclasses, but it's different in all of them, how should I code it?

Should I code like this:

```
class Product {
    private String name;
    double tax;

    Product(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class CarProduct extends Product {
    CarProduct(String name) {
        super(name);
        this.tax = 0.2;
    }
}

class PharmacyProduct extends Product {
    PharmacyProduct(String name) {
        super(name);
        this.tax = 0.05;
    }
}
```

Or like this? Which is more correct?

```
class Product {
    private String name;

    Product(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class CarProduct extends Product {
    private double tax;

    CarProduct(String name) {
        super(name);
        this.tax = 0.2;
    }
}

class PharmacyProduct extends Product {
    private double tax;

    PharmacyProduct(String name) {
        super(name);
        this.tax = 0.05;
    }
}
```

**Update**
<del>following @JB Nizet comment,</del> I altered the way to set the tax value for each subclass:

```
class Product {
    private String name;
    private double tax;

    Product(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    setTax(double tax) {
        this.tax = tax;
    }
}

class CarProduct extends Product {
    CarProduct(String name) {
        super(name);
        this.setTax(0.5);
    }
}

class PharmacyProduct extends Product {
    PharmacyProduct(String name) {
        super(name);
        this.setTax(0.05);
    }
}
```

Is this better than the previous two?

Comment: You can make `Products` abstract.  With this, first approach seems OK, as `tax` is something common to all `is-a Products`

Comment: But shouldn't the classes's field be more encapsulated as possible? Even if we have to duplicate code like the declaration of tax in each subclass?

Comment: You shouldn't even have a tax field at all. Just a method getTax() that returns always the same value. Also, does Java have classes named Strings, Integers, Doubles? No, because an instance of the String class is **one** String. Remove the `s`from your class names: it makes the code awkward and hard to read.

Comment: You're not following my comment. You still have a useless tax field. You should instead have an abstract getTax() method in the base class, and an implementation that returns a constant in each subclass. No need for any field.

Comment: Sorry JB Nizet, I'm a noob in OOP. Must study abstraction...

Answer (score 0):

If tax is a common property that all products should have (which makes sense to me, but depends on your exact usecase), I'd keep the `tax` member in the base class, and have the inheriting classes pass its values to the base constructor:

```
class Product {
    private String name;
    double tax;

    Product(String name, double tax) {
        this.name = name;
        this.tax = tax;
    }
}

class CarProduct extends Product {
    CarProduct(String name) {
        super(name, 0.2);
    }
}

class PharmacyProduct extends Product {
    PharmacyProduct(String name) {
        super(name, 0.05);
    }
}
```

Comment: In my user case I want the tax to be fixed for each subclass and not be set by the user. So it as to be set only by the subclass at the instantiate time. I updated my question to show another possible solution.

Comment: @LuísAlves "to be set only by the subclass at the instantiate time" That's precisely what the above code does.

Comment: But isn't that the same as my first option?

Comment: @LuísAlves it's similar, but not quite the same. In your first option, you leave the inheriting classes to directly manipulate `tax`. In this way, they don't have direct access to it, and can use getters and setters (admittedly, not shown here) for better encapsulation.